# (abbrev-mode 1) not enabling automatic abbreviation

Tags: abbrev

I have an elisp file named `toro.el` that I want to call in my init file

```
(defconst tablet2 
   '( ("is" "s")      ("it" "t")       ("know" "no")
      ("like" "lk")   ("little" "ll")  ("more" "mo")

(defun toro-abbrev ()
  "Enables words to be expanded as one types."
  (interactive)
  (abbrev-mode 1)
  (kill-all-abbrevs)
  (define-abbrev-table 'global-abbrev-table tablet2))

(provide 'toro)
```

I then do

```
(require 'toro)
(toro-abbrev)
```

Yet, the automatic abbrev does not take effect until I call `M-x abbrev-mode` in my buffer.  Why do I have to call `M-x abbrev-mode` when `(toro-abbrev)` should enable `(abbrev-mode 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably because you run `toro-abbrev` in a different buffer than the one where you expect `abbrev-mode` to take effect: the doc string of `abbrev-mode` tells you that it does its job **in the current buffer**. So you have to make the buffer your current buffer and run `toro-abbrev` there. If you do it from lisp, use `with-current-buffer`:

```el
(with-current-buffer "foo" (toro-abbrev))
```

specifically targeting the `foo` buffer.

Comment: Is it possible to automatically enable it globally or by major-mode?  How would the configuration look like?

Comment: There you go again: you ask a question, you get an answer and then you ask a different question in a comment. If you have a second question, ask a different question! How hard is that to understand?